# How to do a server side / safer processing

Tags: php, ajax, security, session, server

I was just hired in a company and I am given a website to modify. The pitfall of the website is that for payment, it uses forms with `post` method to post the values to the IPG URL. These values are `amount`, `invoiceNumber` and etc. The problem is that some expert users can simply use inspect element and change the `amount` value. For example, they can choose an item which is $200 and before going to IPG, change the value to let's say $50 and proceed with the payment.
I have to figure out a way to not allow the users to do so. 
As of now, someone suggested to use sessions for that.
As an update, I paste my code here:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" id="PaymentForm" action="theUrl" style="direction: rtl">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{payment.Amount}}"/>
          <input type='hidden' name='paymentId' value='{{payment.InvoiceNumber}}' />
          <input type='hidden' name='revertURL' value='http://theRevertUrl' />

<ul style="text-align: right">

     <a href="javascript://" ng-click="SetPrePayment();">  </a>
      </ul>
    </form >
```

Any suggestion!?

Comment: Do you have any existing code to share? Otherwise try using CMS.

Comment: Payment gateways typically have a signature field you can use, signing the critical data with a key on your server that the gateway can verify as having come from you. The name of the field and the signature algorithm will vary depending on the gateway in question.